# issue in code "$event.target.checked" in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

Using this example in my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rskaug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**Html in component**

```html
<td><input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(employee.id, $event.target.checked)"></td>
```

**Typescript in component**

```js
onChange(id: any, isChecked: boolean) {
    const idFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.employeeRelatedId;

    if (isChecked) {
      idFormArray.push(new FormControl(id));
    } else {
      let index = idFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == id)
      idFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
```

**Error Detail**

Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

> 45               <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(employee.id, $event.target.checked)">

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you have a Reactive Form already in the template, I am not sure why this `input` isn't also a part of it. Then you could use something like the form group's `valueChanges` observable to listen to it's events.

Being said that, there are multiple quick fixes you could try.

**Option 1: template reference variable**

You could use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#syntax) in the `<input>` element and capture it's `checked` property in the event handler's argument.

```html
<input type="checkbox" #inputBox (change)="onChange(employee?.id, inputBox?.checked)">
```

Here the `#inputBox` is the template reference variable.

**Option 2: disable type checking**

You could disable type checking using [`$any()`](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any) function in the template.

```html
<input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(employee?.id, $any($event.target)?.checked)">
```

The safe navigation operator `?.` is used to avoid potential `possibly undefined` errors.

**Update: working example**

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7rlvbr?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: can you please provide a working example using stackbiz

Comment: Option 3: convert `EventTarget` to `HTMLInputElement` right?

Comment: @MuhammadBilal It is good idea OP create stackblitz  sample and other people forked the link! :)

Comment: @Michaal D I just want to collect selected records related id(s) to perform delete operation on selected records.

Comment: @MuhammadBilal: I've updated the answer with a working example.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi: If possible, could you please say how to convert to an `HTMLInputElement` in the template? It could be done in the controller as shown by @IAfanasov in his answer.

Comment: @MichaelD you are right I mean  in the controller. I said that this is options 3 for fixed the problem not in the template

Comment: @MichaelD please help in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68815148/7186739

Answer (score 2):

`$event.target` is of generic type `EventTarget`. TypeScript is not smart enough to recognize that the event would be triggered by the input and the actual type would be `HTMLInputElement`. You can do such a change to overcome it:

```html
<td><input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(employee.id, $event.target)"></td>
```

```js
onChange(id: any, target: EventTarget | null) {
    const input = target as HTMLInputElement;
    const idFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.employeeRelatedId;

    if (input.checked) {
      idFormArray.push(new FormControl(id));
    } else {
      let index = idFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == id)
      idFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
```

Comment: please see error using your code Error Detail: Argument of type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventTarget'.

Comment: thanks for update, Muhammad! I changed the code to handle this error. It is due to strict type checking. While I find Option 1 from Michael's answer is better than my suggestion (: it is better to go with that

Comment: I followed this example it still tells me eventTarget as checkbox has no checked property.